# How to find out the subnet of the router?

Tags: router

There is a router previously configured to use the subnet different from default. When going to `Local Area Connenection > Properties> .. > Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)> Properties` there is a properties I have to change **manually** to find out what subnet my router located in. It's time consuming and inefficient way to act. The is a broken reset button on th eback of the router. Is there any approach to find out the subnet of the router? *Something like `brute force`*

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just switch to `Obtain an IP address automatically` and then run the command `ipconfig`?

Comment: Have you already tried connecting to your router's administration interface to find out and/or change what you need?

Comment: Are we talking class full or class less routing?

Comment: @moses: It cannot get address automatically. It's written **Undefined Network**.

Comment: @Brian Z: before accessing router administration interface I have to get valid IP, otherwise it's invalid config and no access possible.

Comment: I had similar situation when a router was not configured to run DHCP. The only way in was to assign my computer static ip from router's **subnet**. Fortunately I know the subnet and valid ip range. But in this case I don't.

Comment: The subnet mask parameter applies to your network interface--not to your router.  For that matter there is no "correct" subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've had a Windows box, but you should be able to pull up details showing the netmask and other routing stuff simply by typing "ipconfig" on the command line.  If you can make the command line window not disappear you can simply create a button with that, alternatively maybe write it to a file, then cat the file.

An alternative command would be to use the "route" command and determine the network from that.